# What is the name of "===" operator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, operators, naming

I was wondering if there is widely recognized name for `===` operator. Something like "IIFE" for `(function () {})();`

Comment: identity or strict equality

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I was wondering if there is widely recognized name for === operator.

The names I've heard most commonly are *strict equality operator* and *strict equals operator*. And it turns out that arguably, it has both those names:

The old spec called it the [*strict equals operator*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.4):

> 11.9.4 The Strict Equals Operator ( === )
>
> The production EqualityExpression : EqualityExpression === RelationalExpression is evaluated as follows: ...

Oddly, it's never actually named in the new spec, but the closest is [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-strict-equality-comparison):

> 7.2.13 Strict Equality Comparison
>
> The comparison x === y, where x and y are values, produces true or false. Such a comparison is performed as follows:...

Answer (score 0):

its commonly referred to as strict equals