# JS select correct line in select list

Tags: javascript

I am using this JS code to do some magic. Working perfect to get a variabele and remove unwanted text and display the correct text in a `text field`.

`values 2 or 3 or 5 or 7 etc.` in `<input type="text" id="calc_dikte[0][]" name="calc_dikte[]" value="">`

```
function copy_dikte()
{
    var i;
    var elems = document.getElementsByName('dxf_var_dikte_copy[]');
    var elems_1 = document.getElementsByName('dxf_vars[]');
    var elems_2 = document.getElementsByName('calc_dikte[]');
    var elems_3 = document.getElementsByName('calc_ext[]');
    var l = elems.length;
    var z;
    z=0;

    for(i=0; i<l; i++)
    {
        if(elems_3[i].value == 'dxf')
        {
            elems[i].value = document.getElementById('dxf_var_dikte').value;

            var elems_1_split_1 = (elems_1[i].value).split(elems[i].value+'=');
            var elems_1_split_2 = (elems_1_split_1[1]).split(',');

            if(isNaN(elems_1_split_2[0])) { elems_2[i].value = ''; }
            else { elems_2[i].value = parseFloat(elems_1_split_2[0]); }
        }
    }
}
```

So this works, but now the form field has changed from `text` to `select` like:

```
<select id="calc_dikte[0][]" name="calc_dikte[]">
<option value="">
<option value="2|2000">2</option>
<option value="3|2000">3</option>
<option value="5|2000">5</option>
<option value="7|2000">7</option>
</select>
```

Therefore I have changed my JS code ([with some tips from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989324/javascript-set-dropdown-selected-item-based-on-option-text)) to:

```
function copy_dikte()
{
    var i;
    var elems = document.getElementsByName('dxf_var_dikte_copy[]');
    var elems_1 = document.getElementsByName('dxf_vars[]');
    var elems_2 = document.getElementsByName('calc_dikte[]');
    var elems_3 = document.getElementsByName('calc_ext[]');
    var l = elems.length;
    var z;
    z=0;

    for(i=0; i<l; i++)
    {
        if(elems_3[i].value == 'dxf')
        {
            elems[i].value = document.getElementById('dxf_var_dikte').value;

            var elems_1_split_1 = (elems_1[i].value).split(elems[i].value+'=');
            var elems_1_split_2 = (elems_1_split_1[1]).split(',');

            var sel = elems_2[i];
            var val = parseFloat(elems_1_split_2[0]);

            for(var m=0, n=sel.options.length; m<n; m++)
            {
                if(sel.options[i].innerHTML === val)
                {
                   sel.selectedIndex = m;
                   break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this is not working, no item is selected in the select list, no errors are shown.
Please help me out change to a working code to have the correct line selected. It should not select on the `value` but in the text between the `><`
option value="5|2000">**5**</option

If I check with

```
for(var m=0, n=sel.options.length; m<n; m++) {
alert('sel = '+sel.options[i].innerHTML+'\nval = '+val);
}
```

I see that `val` is correct. But `sel`  is just the number as used in `$i` so `0` `1` `2`

Comment: By the way: You probably can replace `val = parseFloat(xx)` with `val = +xx`, which is shorter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code to get this working:

```
function copy_dikte()
{
    var i;
    var elems = document.getElementsByName('dxf_var_dikte_copy[]');
    var elems_1 = document.getElementsByName('dxf_vars[]');
    var elems_2 = document.getElementsByName('calc_dikte[]');
    var elems_3 = document.getElementsByName('calc_ext[]');
    var l = elems.length;
    var z;
    z=0;

    for(i=0; i<l; i++)
    {
        if(elems_3[i].value == 'dxf')
        {
            elems[i].value = document.getElementById('dxf_var_dikte').value;

            var elems_1_split_1 = (elems_1[i].value).split(elems[i].value+'=');
            var elems_1_split_2 = (elems_1_split_1[1]).split(',');

            var val = parseFloat(elems_1_split_2[0]);
            var sel = elems_2[i];

            var opts = sel.options;

            for (var opt, j = 0; opt = opts[j]; j++)
            {
                if (opt.text == val)
                {
                    sel.selectedIndex = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using a [`strict equals`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33526533/what-is-the-name-of-operator-in-javascript) operator to compare a `Number` (`parseFloat`) agains `.innerHTML`, which is always a `string`.

Convert `sel.options[i].innerHTML` to a `Number` aswell:

```
if (parseFloat(sel.options[i].innerHTML) === val) {
  sel.selectedIndex = m;
  break;
}
```

If you want to filter out invalid numbers (`NaN`s), use `!isNaN(val)` aswell.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Still the same issue.


If I check with

    for(var m=0, n=sel.options.length; m<n; m++) {
    alert('sel = '+sel.options[i].innerHTML+'\nval = '+val);
    }

I see that `val` is correct. But `sel ` is just the number as used in `$i` so `0` `1` `2`

Comment: Could you try to use `parseInt`? `float`s are inaccurate. Sometimes `parseFloat("1")` can be result in a `float(1.000000001)` or even `float(0.999999999)`. You could use `if (parseInt(sel.options[i].innerHTML)*1000 === parseInt(val*1000))`.

Comment: If that does not solve your problem, please provide an executable example e.g. on https://codepen.io/

Comment: Is seems like I can set it based on the value `elems_2[i].value = parseFloat(elems_1_split_2[0]);`  But I need to set based on the text.